# RuntimeException: InvocationTargetException in web browser

Tags: java, applet, console, rfid, runtimeexception

My Java Applet works perfectly fine when I run from Netbeans and the jar file created works fine too. However, when I embed the applet into the browser, I have this error "RuntimeException java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException" I have surfed through to debug this error but I couldn't seem to find a solution for my codes. Please help. Thank You.

Here are my codes:

**SerialTest.java** (this is my main class, in the main method, I call the applet so that whatever that should be printed in the Java console will be printed in the applet instead)

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import gnu.io.CommPortIdentifier;
import gnu.io.SerialPort;
import gnu.io.SerialPortEvent;
import gnu.io.SerialPortEventListener;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class SerialTest implements SerialPortEventListener {

    SerialPort serialPort;

    /**
     * The port we're normally going to use.
     */
    public static final String PORT_NAMES[] = {
        "/dev/cu.usbserial-A9014NQP" //, Mac OS X
    //"/dev/ttyUSB0", // Linux
    //"COM3", // Windows
    };
    /**
     * A BufferedReader which will be fed by a InputStreamReader converting the
     * bytes into characters making the displayed results codepage independent
     */
    public BufferedReader input;
    /**
     * The output stream to the port
     */
    public OutputStream output;
    /**
     * Milliseconds to block while waiting for port open
     */
    public static final int TIME_OUT = 2000;
    /**
     * Default bits per second for COM port.
     */
    public static final int DATA_RATE = 9600;

    public void initialize() {
        CommPortIdentifier portId = null;
        Enumeration portEnum = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers();

        //First, Find an instance of serial port as set in PORT_NAMES.
        while (portEnum.hasMoreElements()) {
            CommPortIdentifier currPortId = (CommPortIdentifier) portEnum.nextElement();
            for (String portName : PORT_NAMES) {
                if (currPortId.getName().equals(portName)) {
                    portId = currPortId;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if (portId == null) {
            //portnotdetected = "Could not find COM port.";
            System.out.println("Could not find COM port.");
            return;
        }

        try {
            // open serial port, and use class name for the appName.
            serialPort = (SerialPort) portId.open(this.getClass().getName(),
                    TIME_OUT);

            // set port parameters
            serialPort.setSerialPortParams(DATA_RATE,
                    SerialPort.DATABITS_8,
                    SerialPort.STOPBITS_1,
                    SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);

            // open the streams
            input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(serialPort.getInputStream()));
            output = serialPort.getOutputStream();

            // add event listeners
            serialPort.addEventListener(this);
            serialPort.notifyOnDataAvailable(true);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e.toString());
        }
    }

    /**
     * This should be called when you stop using the port. This will prevent
     * port locking on platforms like Linux.
     */
    public synchronized void close() {
        if (serialPort != null) {
            serialPort.removeEventListener();
            serialPort.close();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Handle an event on the serial port. Read the data and print it.
     */
    public synchronized void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent oEvent) {

        if (oEvent.getEventType() == SerialPortEvent.DATA_AVAILABLE) {
            try {
                String inputLine = input.readLine().trim();
                //String readID = inputLine.substring(1);

                System.out.println("Read Tag ID: " + inputLine); //this is the tagID read

                Connection conn = null;

                try {

                    String userName = "root";
                    String password = "root";
                    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:8889/RFID";

                    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
                    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, userName, password);

                    //System.out.println("Database connection established");
                    Statement stmt = null;
                    ResultSet rs = null;
                    //SQL query command
                    String SQL = "SELECT * FROM Inventory WHERE (SerialID = '" + inputLine + "')";
                    //String SQL = "SELECT * FROM Inventory";
                    stmt = conn.createStatement();
                    rs = stmt.executeQuery(SQL);


                    if (rs != null && rs.next()) {
                        String SerialID = rs.getString("SerialID");
                        String name = rs.getString("Name");
                        String description = rs.getString("Description");

                        if (inputLine.equals(SerialID)) {

                            System.out.println(SerialID + "\t " + name + "\t " + description + "\n"); //from Database

                        }
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Sorry Tag ID " + inputLine + " not found database \n");
                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {

                    System.err.println("Cannot connect to database server");
                    e.printStackTrace();

                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.err.println(e.toString());
            }
        }
        // Ignore all the other eventTypes, but you should consider the other ones.
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new SerialApp();

        SerialTest main = new SerialTest();
        main.initialize();
        Thread t = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                //the following line will keep this app alive for 1000 seconds,
                //waiting for events to occur and responding to them (printing incoming messages to console).
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000000);
                } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
                }
            }
        };
        t.start();

        System.out.println("Started");

        /*
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

         String userInput = scanner.next();
         if ("q".equals(userInput)) {
         System.exit(0);
         }      
         */
    }
}
```

**SerialApp.java** (this is where I create my applet)

```
import java.io.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.JApplet;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class SerialApp extends JApplet implements Runnable, ActionListener
{
    public JFrame frame;
    public TextArea textArea;
    public Thread reader;
    public Thread reader2;
    public boolean quit;

    public final PipedInputStream pin=new PipedInputStream(); 
    public final PipedInputStream pin2=new PipedInputStream(); 

    Thread errorThrower; // just for testing (Throws an Exception at this Console

        public void init() {

        }

    public SerialApp()
    {
        // create all components and add them
        frame=new JFrame("RFID");
        Dimension screenSize=Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        Dimension frameSize=new Dimension((int)(screenSize.width/2),(int)(screenSize.height/2));
        int x=(int)(frameSize.width/2);
        int y=(int)(frameSize.height/2);
        frame.setBounds(x,y,frameSize.width,frameSize.height);
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

                textArea=new TextArea();
        textArea.setEditable(false);

                Container container = getContentPane();// Get the content pane of the frame
                container.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                container.add(textArea, BorderLayout.CENTER);

                //Button button=new Button("clear"); //create button

        /*
                Panel panel=new Panel();
        panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        panel.add(textArea,BorderLayout.CENTER);
        //panel.add(button,BorderLayout.SOUTH); //button location
                */

        frame.add(container);
                frame.setVisible(true); 

        //button.addActionListener(this); //add button

        try
        {
            PipedOutputStream pout=new PipedOutputStream(this.pin);
            System.setOut(new PrintStream(pout,true)); 
        } 
        catch (java.io.IOException io)
        {
            textArea.append("Couldn't redirect STDOUT to this console\n"+io.getMessage());
        }
        catch (SecurityException se)
        {
            textArea.append("Couldn't redirect STDOUT to this console\n"+se.getMessage());
        } 

        try 
        {
            PipedOutputStream pout2=new PipedOutputStream(this.pin2);
            System.setErr(new PrintStream(pout2,true));
        } 
        catch (java.io.IOException io)
        {
            textArea.append("Couldn't redirect STDERR to this console\n"+io.getMessage());
        }
        catch (SecurityException se)
        {
            textArea.append("Couldn't redirect STDERR to this console\n"+se.getMessage());
        }       

        quit=false; // signals the Threads that they should exit

        // Starting two seperate threads to read from the PipedInputStreams             
        //
        reader=new Thread(this);
        reader.setDaemon(true); 
        reader.start(); 
        //
        reader2=new Thread(this);   
        reader2.setDaemon(true);    
        reader2.start();

    }


    public synchronized void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt)
    {
        textArea.setText("");
    }

    public synchronized void run()
    {
        try
        {           
            while (Thread.currentThread()==reader)
            {
                try { this.wait(100);}catch(InterruptedException ie) {}
                if (pin.available()!=0)
                {
                    String input=this.readLine(pin);
                    textArea.append(input);
                }
                if (quit) return;
            }

            while (Thread.currentThread()==reader2)
            {
                try { this.wait(100);}catch(InterruptedException ie) {}
                if (pin2.available()!=0)
                {
                    String input=this.readLine(pin2);
                    textArea.append(input);
                }
                if (quit) return;
            }           
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            textArea.append("\nConsole reports an Internal error.");
            textArea.append("The error is: "+e);            
        }

        // just for testing (Throw a Nullpointer after 1 second)
        if (Thread.currentThread()==errorThrower)
        {
            try { this.wait(1000); }catch(InterruptedException ie){}
            throw new NullPointerException("Application test: throwing an NullPointerException It should arrive at the console");
        }

    }

    public synchronized String readLine(PipedInputStream in) throws IOException
    {
        String input="";
        do
        {
            int available=in.available();
            if (available==0) break;
            byte b[]=new byte[available];
            in.read(b);
            input=input+new String(b,0,b.length);                                                       
        }while( !input.endsWith("\n") &&  !input.endsWith("\r\n") && !quit);
        return input;
    }               
}
```

**applet.html**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Applet</title>
</head>

<body>
<applet code="SerialTest.class" archive="SerialApplet.jar" width="550" height="550">
</applet>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Post a stacktrace, without it difficult to tell you what caused the exception above.

Comment: stacktrace will be very useful

Comment: As an aside `//waiting for events to occur and responding to them (printing incoming messages to console).
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000000);`  It has long been known that 'coding by magic' does not work.  That lines of code with comment indicates that's what you are attempting.  Blocking the EDT will simply cause the entire app. to freeze.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have this error "RuntimeException
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException"

Because , You are overruling the rules provided by sandbox of java Applet. I guess, `gnu.io.SerialPort` has something to do with this. Look at here to know more about applet sandbox: [What Applets Can and Cannot Do](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/security.html)

Comment: InvocationTargetException is just a wrapper around the actual exception thrown by the reflectively called method. Nothing can be concluded from it, especially without a stacktrace.

Comment: *"I guess.."*  You should stop guessing, ..seriously.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Hi, I'm new here. How do I obtain a stacktrace?

Answer (score 2):

> I have this error "RuntimeException
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException"

This is because You are putting the applet code tag as :

```
<applet code="SerialTest.class" archive="SerialApplet.jar" width="550" height="550">
```

And `SerialTest` is not an Applet..Applets don't use a main method to execute. Instead they are started with their `init()` and `start()` methods. Have a look at the following official tutorial to know more about Applets : [Java Applets](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/subclass.html)

Comment: *"Instead they are started with their `init()` and `start()` methods."*  It is not necessary to use either of those methods in order to get a working applet.  Though it makes a lot of *sense* to use the `init()` method to construct an applet GUI, it is also *possible* to just define a `public` constructor and create the GUI within that instead.

Comment: @AndrewThompson" So does it mean that an applet can be started without `init()` or `start()` method defined defined within it?